# Rails checking model to see if all fields are empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, model, helper

As far as I've tested it, this helper method works exactly as it's meant to, however I want to know if there is any easier, built-in, or smarter way to run this check! I also am aware that having this in the ApplicationHelper probably isn't ideal. Not sure if I should just put it in the parent object (the Inspection), some other model, or leave as is.

With `is_model_empty?` I need to run through every field of any one of eleven different (but similar) models to check to see if all of them are Empty. All of them except the :id, :inspection_id, :created_at, and :updated_at fields which will never be blank. Empty can be nil, can be [], or can be ['']. An empty string would actually imply that the user entered something so that won't be included. The value can be either a string or an array so `.empty?` won't work.

```
def is_model_empty?(model)
    model.attributes.each do |k, v|
        unless ['id', 'inspection_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'].include?(k)
            return false unless v.nil? || v == [] || v == [""]
        end
    end
    true
end
```

The eleven models all belong to the Inspection and each has a `has_one` relationship:

```
has_one :first_info_section
has_one :second_info_section
has_one :third_info_section
```

Any advice/feedback would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading!

-Dave

Comment: Your code will always return `true`. You never assign anything to `answer` after the initial assignment.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, but any time that the value in the field is not equal to nil, [], or [""], it will automatically exit the method and return false. (`return false unless v.nil? || v == [] || v == [""]`). It only takes one field to have some text or an array in it to tell the method that it is not empty!

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, David. In that case why assign `answer` at all if you could just put `true` at the bottom? ;)

Comment: Lol just edited it to do so, thanks Jordan!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method can be simplifed as an instance method on each of the models.  If the attribute exceptions are the same for all the models you can create a shared library and include it each of the models.

`app/models/empty_detection.rb`:

```
module EmptyDetection
  def empty?
    attributes.all? do |k, v|
      ['id', 'inspection_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'].include?(k) || v.nil? || v == [] || v == [""]
    end
  end
end
```

Include that module in each model you want to be able to check for the empty conditions.  For example, the Widget model:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  include EmptyDetection
end
```

Now you can use it on any instance of a Widget:

```
widget = Widget.find(45)
widget.empty?
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I was looking for, already implemented and (still) works beautifully! Thanks for the help and your time, infused.

Answer (score 2):

```rb
user.attributes.values.all?(&:blank?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really basic refactor:

```
def is_empty?(model)
  whitelist = %w[ id inspection_id created_at updated_at ]

  model.attributes.all? do |attr, val|
    whitelist.exclude?(attr) || val.nil? || val == [] || val == [""]
  end
end
```

What you really want, though, is a validator, which is described in the [Active Record Validations Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators):

In this case it would look like this:

```
class EmptyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  WHITELIST = %w[ id inspection_id created_at updated_at ].freeze

  def validate(record)
    return unless model.attributes.all? do |attr, val|
      WHITELIST.exclude?(attr) || empty?(val)
    end
    record.errors[:base] << "You missed one!"
  end

  private
  def empty?(val)
    val.nil? || val == [] || val == [""]
  end
end
```

Then, in each of your models...

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with EmptyValidator
end
```

I hope that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks Jordan, that was very helpful and will come in handy whenever I need to run validations on the model to ensure one state or the other. With this project, both cases are perfectly acceptable (an empty model vs a full model) so although the architecture probably leaves something to be desired, I don't need to raise any exceptions or log errors, just need to return true or false depending on the data (or lack thereof) in each model. Appreciate your time!